# C programming - Inverting a string

Tags: c, arrays, function

In this program i'm trying to invert a string using 2 arrays: 
The problem here is the program keeps writing the character "P" as the only output and i can't seem to figure out how to solve this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define TAM 256

int get_string(char string[TAM]);    
int invert_string(char string[TAM]);    
int string_out(char string[TAM]);

int main(){
    char string[TAM]={0};  // always initialize a string to be completely zero, or unexpected behaviour may occur    
    get_string(string);
    invert_string(string);

    return 0;
}

int get_string(char string[TAM]){
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s",string);
    return 0;
}

int invert_string(char string[TAM]){
    char temporary_string[TAM]={0};
    int i,j;

    for(i=TAM,j=0;i>=0;i--){
        if(string[i]== ' '){
            continue;
        }else{
            temporary_string[j] = string[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    printf("debug : temp string is : %s",temporary_string);
    return 0;
}

int string_out(char string[TAM]){
    printf("%s",string);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In invert_string start i with TAM - 1.

Comment: the function: invert_string() is missing a critical statement.  I.E. the temporary_string needs to be copied back to the original string.  Also, skipping ' ' characters is not part of the problem description.  if strlen() were used, rather than TAM, then trailing '\0' would never be accessed.

Comment: this line: 'scanf("%s",string);' should 1) check the returned value from scanf to assure the operation was successful,  2) limit the max length of string so there will be no buffer overflow.  3) scanf will stop at the first 'white space' (like a ' ') so would be much better to use fgets() then replace the trailing newline with '\0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an array declaration / definition of `arr[256]`, the last element is `arr[255]`.

In your `for()` loop,

```
for(i=TAM,j=0;i>=0;i--)
```

you're  accessing `arr[256]` [*267th element, considering index starts from `0`*] which is out-of-bound access and hence produces [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Then, the terminating NULL in the source array should be taken care of separately.

You need to have something like

```
if((string[i]== ' ') || (string[i]== '\0')){//....
```

Otherwise, the terminating NULL will become the first *vaild* element in the destination array, thus will end up `print`ing *nothing*.

Lastly, don't forget to NULL terminate the new array.

```
temporary_string[j] = '\0';
```

Note: Once you'vre fixed this version of code, think of some optimization.

Check the below code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define TAM 256

int get_string(char string[TAM]);

int invert_string(char string[TAM]);

int string_out(char string[TAM]);

int main(){
    char string[TAM]={0};  // always initialize a string to be completely zero, or unexpected behaviour may occur

    get_string(string);
    invert_string(string);

    return 0;
}

int get_string(char string[TAM]){
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s",string);

    return 0;
}

int invert_string(char string[TAM]){
    char temporary_string[TAM]={0};
    int i,j;

    for(i=TAM-1,j=0;i>=0;i--){
        if((string[i]== ' ') || (string[i]== '\0')){
            continue;
        }else{
            temporary_string[j] = string[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    temporary_string[j] = '\0';
    printf("debug : temp string is : %s\n",temporary_string);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you think it is a good idea to start the loop from `i=TAM-1` instead of `strlen(string) -1`?

Comment: @Gopi Its a very bad idea. But if we simply move to your solution, the out-of-bound access [IMO, which is more _fatal_ than useless looping] _may_ go unnoticed. That's why I took that angle.

Comment: We can avoid it by having a check before the loop like `if(strlen(string) <= TAM-1) i =strlen(string) -1` `else printf("String cannot be reversed\n");` This way we avoid both array out of bound and unnecessary looping

Comment: @Gopi isn't in current scenario `if(strlen(string) <= TAM)` will always be TRUE? and next, I wanted to _make_ a point about the wrong usage of `for(i=TAM,..` part. Nevertheless, Your suggestion is totally valid and _should_ be followed.

Comment: It needs to be TRUE in order to move ahead . It should be `<=TAM-1` as shown in my comment not `<=TAM`

Answer (score 2):

Try this code in `invert_string` function:

```
int i,j;
for(i=strlen(string)-1,j=0;i>=0;i--){ // u can take variable and save length or directly pass length
    if(string[i]== ' '){
        continue;
    }else{
        temporary_string[j++] = string[i];
    }
}
temporary_string[j] = '\0';   //Make last index NULL
printf("%s",temporary_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make you loop condition starting with 255.

```
for ( i=TAM-1 ; j=0; i>=0 ; i--)
   ...
```

256 is array out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of issues with your code. At first  you cannot start with 256 as i mentioned in the comment. Again you don't know how much is the length of the source string. Even if u have taken the size to be 256 the string inputted  from the terminal can be of  length smaller than 256. So first you must know what is the size of the string inputted from the terminal. After that start with strlen(string) - 1 and copy until i becomes 0. Then do temporary_string[strlen(string)-1]='\0'